# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using javascript to move up, down a text row, when I run on Chrome it happen an issue on console bug browser

```js
function up_move(index) {
  var frm = document.writeForm;
  var opts = frm["ans_list" + index].options
  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i > 0) {
      tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
      opts[i].removeChild(opts[i].childNodes[0]);
      opts[i - 1].insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin", tmp).selected = true;
    }
  }
  setting_val(index);
}

function down_move(index) {
  var frm = document.writeForm;
  var opts = frm["ans_list" + index].options
  for (var i = opts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i < opts.length - 1) {
      tmp = opts[i].cloneNode(true);
      opts[i].removeChild(opts[i].childNodes[0]);
      opts[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", tmp).selected = true;
    }
  }

  setting_val(index);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="javasript:up_move('1');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▲ Order</span></a>
<a href="#" onClick="javasript:down_move('2');" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">▼ Order</span></a>
```

this is bug on console browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>   at up_move (write_form.jsp:367)

How to fix this error?

Comment: I added your code in a snippet, yet it seems to produce a different error as the question is missing a lot of the relevant HTML. Can you please edit the code you've shown so that it shows the exact issue you have.

Comment: Well you're passing `true` to `removeChild`, when it expects a node.

Comment: Tks @Utkanos: What's your meaning? should I remove 'true'?

Comment: `removeChild()` expects a node as its only argument; you are passing a boolean, not a node. Ergo, you're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to correct the syntax for removeChild. It can be like this:

```
opts[i].removeChild(opts[i].childNodes[0]);
```

It will remove the first child node of opts[i]

Comment: Hi @Abhilasha: I have updated source and result as above, it can order up, down text, but it isn't as expected

Comment: Can you share the required HTML code. For Example the tags for "ans_list+{index}"